# Can you remove a bad save from a task?

Tags: tfs

I wrote a silly amount on a task in a sprint.  I filled in the value "1,000,000" for "Remaining Work".  Now the Burndown chart has adjusted itself on the scale of a million.  That means our piddly 80 hours of team work isn't showing on the chart at all :(.

Can I remove this value from remaining work somehow now that it has been added and saved?

Comment: Do you have any concern to re-edit the value and save?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT No that would be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just edit it to the value you want and resave.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting in TFS makes use of Sql Server Analysis Server, or OLAP cube. This cube is by default refreshed **every two hours**. After you edit the value, you can [manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services cube](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube), then check the Burndown chat again.

Summary how to manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services cube:

1. Log on to the application-tier server and open the Warehouse Control Web Service by entering the following URL in a supported web browser:

http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx

2. Choose **ProcessWarehouse**, click **Invoke**:

[image]

The service returns **True** when it successfully starts the processing of the warehouse and **False** if it is not successful. A value of **False** indicates that the warehouse is currently being processed.

To determine the processing status of the warehouse choose **GetProcessingStatus** to check the process status.
Warehouse processing is completed when the GetProcessingStatus service returns a value of **Idle**, and a value of **Succeeded** for **Common Structures Warehouse Sync** and for each warehouse for each team project collection.

3. Choose **ProcessAnalysisDatabase**. For **processingType**, type either **Incremental** or **Full**. Click **Invoke**:

[image]

The service returns **True** when it successfully starts the processing of the cube and **False** if it is not successful. A value of **False** indicates that the cube is currently being processed.

Cube processing is completed when the **GetProcessingStatus** service returns a value of **Idle**, and a value of **Succeeded** for the following jobs.

- **Full Analysis Database Sync**
- **Incremental Analysis Database Sync**

If manually processing still doesn't work, you can try to delete the Tfs_Analysis database and recreate it using TFS Admin Console. To delete the Tfs_Analysis database, you can connect to **Analysis Service** using **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, expand the **Databases** node, and delete the Tfs_Analysis database.

To recreate the Tfs_Analysis database, please refer to the following steps:

1. Launch TFS Admin Console>>Application Tier>>Reporting, in the right panel, click **Edit** to open the **Reporting** windows.
2. Under the **Analysis Services** tab, input the Tfs_Analysis under **Database** textbox, and re-provide the required account under **Account for accessing data source**.
3. Click **Ok** to generate the Tfs_Analysis database in **Analysis Services**.
4. Click **Start Jobs** and **Start Rebuild** to rebuild warehouse and the Analysis Services database.

Comment: Can you clarify the steps needed to do this?  Yesterday evening I changed the value from 1M to 24.  Today the burndown still shows "1,000,000"